# Configuring, testing, and deploying React web app on one page of website

Tags: html, reactjs, directory

I have a standard HTML/CSS/JS website and I'd like to implement React for the contact form. I'd like to make it so that users can access the contact form by following or clicking on the link [www.mywebsite.com/contact](http://www.mywebsite.com/contact). I created a folder in my website directory named "contact" and installed the react dependencies. If I run my website using `php -S 127.0.0.1:4300`, and go to the directory /contact, I get the response, "The requested resource /contact was not found on this server.". So, my question is, how can I accomplish implementing a react page in a directory of HTML/CSS/JS files? I found this link in React documentation, but I'm not sure if that explains what I'm trying to do. https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project

I have the basic code below in the index.js file:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Additionally, when I load 127.0.0.1:4300, which is what port the React app I created is on, I get the json response `{"error":"Invalid auth token"}`. Could this be due to cache from another project I've worked on? There is no auth token verification in the react app I created as it's brand new upon entering `create-react-app` in the terminal. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.